# Python one class produces two types

Tags: python, class, types, python-typing, python-3.11

I have a `src` directory containing a `helpers` directory. Inside of the modules inside of the `helpers` directory,
I use

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

to make relative imports work.

I have a `command` dataclass in one of the helpers, but there seem to be two types depending from where it's called.

I have a function like this:

```py
@dataclass
class Command:
    name: str
    description: str
    # ...

class CommandClass():
    commands: list[Command] = []
    def attach_command(self, command: Command) -> None:
        self.commands.append(command)
```

But somehow the type for a manually constructed `Command` inside of `attach_command` is not the same as the one of the `command` argument.

```py
       # ...
       assert type(command) == type(Command("my_name", "my_description")) # false
       # type(command): <class 'command.Command'>
       # type(Command("my_name", "my_description")): <class 'helpers.command.Command'>
```

I was expecting both to at least be evaluated to be the same.

### Minimal reproducible example

A minimal reproducible example can be found [here](https://replit.com/@ElBe-Plaq/stackoverflowExample#main.py). It's not small, but it shows my issue. It also made me realize, that I should have added more information above.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows how you're doing these imports and how you're calling the method.

Comment: Do you have 2 classes called `Command` in that file?

Comment: What are `type(command).__module__` and `Command.__module__` ? Judging by the `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))` hack, I'll bet you have one `Command` class defined at "top-level" when `__name__ == "__main__"` and another equivalent but non-_identical_ class defined by an import statement. The assertion shown will work by identity.

Comment: @Barmar I will add the example.
@JohnLaRooy I do not have 2 classes called `Command` in the file.
@wim `Command.__module__` returns `helpers.command` and `type(command).__module__` returns `command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a Path problem. As you change `sys.path` to allow relative imports, you managed to load 2 instances of the `command` module, one with a path (relative to the current `sys.path` at the time of loading) being `helpers.command`, the latter with a path being `command`.

That is the reason why relative imports are normally restricted inside packages, and why a package is a module having a `__path__` attribute. The goal of that machinery is to make sure that a module should never have 2 distinct paths.

Workaround:

A simple workaround would be to always include a module from the same path. In your example, it is enough to change `import command` with `from helpers import command` in plugin.py:

```
import os
import sys

from helpers import command

plugins = []


class Plugin():
    ...
```

But IMHO the real solution would be to stop playing with `sys.path` and properly convert `src` to a neat and clean package.